# Getting garbled characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, encoding

My aim here is to convert the original xml file through some xsl to the destination having a utf-8 encoding. Here is the original xml file with the following header:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
```

I'm transforming this using xsl to another xml file. The xsl file has the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" 
            encoding="UTF-8" 
            indent="yes" 
            xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
  XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(FileName);
  XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
  myXslTrans.Load("C:/test/test.xsl");
  XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(destinationFile, Encoding.UTF8);
  myWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  myWriter.Indentation = 4;

   myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
   myWriter.Close();
```

The output of this is I get a garbled arabic text at destinationfile. How do get this to read proper arabic text.

**EDIT, Question 2:**

The original XML file is missing  the closing root/child tags. How do I edit this xml to include these in.

e.g. original xml file, missing closing for aaaa and nnnn. How do I edit using C# to get them in.

```
<aaaa>
<nnnn)
<rrrr>
</rrrr>
```

Comment: If you read the input XML file and then write it back out again **without** transforming it is it still garbled?  (The idea is to identify whether or not its the transformation or simply the loading of the XML file which is causing this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your original XML file contains Arabic characters then its XML declaration is lying - the file is not `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` as that encoding cannot represent Arabic.

If you can determine what encoding the original file *really* uses you can force the file to be read in that encoding by using the `XPathDocument` constructor that takes a `TextReader` instead of the one that takes a file name. For Arabic, the encoding is probably Windows-1256.

Comment: I checked the original file with notepad++, it says ansi. But in the declaration it says: encoding='ISO-8859-1'. Is there a possibility to have this converted to utf-8 before I pass it to the xslt processor. How can this be done.

Comment: @user726720 You don't need to "convert" it, just load it with `new XPathDocument(new StreamReader(FileName, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256")))` (or whatever the correct encoding should be).